# Inverse of $A$ for valid $a$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 &1 \\ a& 0 &1 \\ 1& a &0 \end{pmatrix}$$

I am asked to find the values of a where my matrix A is invertible. It is invertible when $\det(A) \neq 0$, and that is when $a^{2} - a \neq 0$ or in other words when $a(a-1) \neq 0$

I have now found the valid values of a ($a \neq 0$ and $a \neq 1$), but now I am asked to show $A^{-1}$ for all valid $a$.

The key says it will be represented as:
$$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{a(a-1)}\begin{pmatrix} -a & a &0 \\ 1& -1 &a-1 \\ a^2 &-a &0 \end{pmatrix}$$

But show no steps on how to reach that conclusion. If anyone could shed any light on how I do to represent $A^{-1}$ when after I found the valid values for $a$.

Comment: Can you find the co-factor matrix and hence the adjoint?

Comment: Does this help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Inversion_of_3.C3.973_matrices ?

Comment: It depends how much you know about inverses. Suppose you know nothing except that you want a matrix $B$ such that $BA=I$. Then looking at the row 1, col 2 element you deduce that $b_{1,3}=0$. Looking at the row 1, col 3 element you deduce that $b_{1,1}=-b_{1,2}$. Then looking at the row 1, col 1 element you find $b_{1,1}$ etc.

Answer (score 3):

### Hint:

Solve for $x_{ij}$:
$$\begin{pmatrix}  x_{11}& x_{12} &x_{13}\\ x_{21}& x_{22} &x_{23}\\ x_{31}& x_{32} &x_{33} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 &1 \\ a& 0 &1 \\ 1& a &0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 &0 \\ 0& 1 &0 \\ 0& 0 &1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

I think, cramers rule will do the job. 
In this case, let $A$ be an $3\times3$ matrix,

then 
$$ A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(A)} \cdot A^{ad} $$

where $A^{ad}$ is the adjugate matrix.

For more information consider [Wikiepdia Cramer's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_rule)